# OpenFileDialog in Avalonia - Error with ShowAsync

Tags: .net, openfiledialog, avaloniaui

**Background:**

I have been using Avalonia to develop a cross-platform UI. To learn it I am trying to  creating a simple program that opens a .txt file using `OpenFileDialog` and displays its contents in a `ComboBox` in another window.

I am trying to write a method that opens file dialog and returns the path the user opened. I am using a button with a Click event to open file dialog and put the specified path in a `TextBox` for the user to see. Since I am new to both WPF and Avalonia, I am not sure how to proceed.

**Problem:**

I have created the UI view and a view model. The view model uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` to display the selected file path in a `TextBox`, which I have default set to the C drive.

Now I want to use `OpenFileDialog` to update that path with the path to the .txt file the user has selected. I found an example that demonstrates `OpenFileDialog`, but it doesn't seem to work for me and I don't really understand how it should work.

TxtView.xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path}" Margin="0 0 5 0" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" />
<Button Content="Browse" Click="OnBrowseClicked" Margin="0 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1" />
```

TxtView.xaml.cs:

```
public async Task GetPath()
{
   var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   dialog.Filters.Add(new FileDialogFilter() { Name = "Text", Extensions = { "txt" } });
   dialog.AllowMultiple = true;

   var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

   if (result != null)
   {
      await GetPath(result);
   }
}

public void OnBrowseClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
   var context = this.DataContext as TxtViewModel;
   context.Path = "path";
}
```

TxtViewModel.cs

```
class TxtViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _path;

   public string Path
   {
      get => _path;
      set
      {
         if (value != _path)
         {
            _path = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }
   }  

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string 
   propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

}
```

The error I am getting with this code is with the `ShowAsync()` in the `TxtView.xaml.cs` file. The error says

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'parent' of 'OpenFileDialog.ShowAsync(Window)'

I have tried `ShowAsync(this)` which fixes the error with `ShowAsync` but now gives me the error

> Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'Txt2List.Views.TxtView' to 'Avalonia.Controls.Window'

All help is appreciated and I apologize if I am not clear, I am completely new to Avalonia, WPF, and XAML so I am learning. Please let me know if there is additional information I can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dialog.ShowAsync();` has a `Window parent` parameter which currently is mandatory. You are probably using an outdated Avalonia version (0.7) where it wasn't specified in the method signature.

You can get the Window for a mapped control by calling `(Window)control.GetVisualRoot()`

Comment: I am currently using version 0.8 of Avalonia. I am not sure what to put for the Window parent field to get it to work, the examples I have found either leave it blank or use "this" as the parameter.
Also can you explain how to use the (Window)control.GetVisualRoot() in this situation?

Comment: `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog` accepts a `Window` as its parameter, so it needs to be passed one. You can get a `Window` instance associated with your control by calling `GetVisualRoot` extension method and casting the returned value to `Window`.

See example usage here: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/DialogsPage.xaml.cs

Comment: That worked in resolving the error, thanks for the explanation. Now I'd like to return the file path selected by the user using OpenFileDialog. Is there a way for me to return the string of the file path from my GetPath() method so I can access it content and display the path selected to the user? When I try to return the result from GetPath() as a string, it returns a Task<string> and tells me "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> to string".

Comment: You can use `async void` in event handlers and just `await` tasks

Comment: I made these changes, but now when Browse is clicked and file dialog is opened, after a file is selected and opened, file dialog reopens and doesn't update my binding for the text box. Essentially, after file dialog opens it keeps reopening until the program is terminated.